# Can proof by contradiction and counterexample by used at the same proof?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Here is a part of a theorem:

If $\alpha>1$ and $x\ge-1$ then $(1+x)^\alpha \ge 1 + \alpha x$

I was wondering if I could use proof by contradiction and counterexample at the same time.

Assume that $(1+x)^\alpha < 1 + \alpha x$ and take $\alpha =2 $ and $ x=10$.   $11^2<1+20$. Since this is a contradiction, $\alpha>1$ and $x\ge-1$ then $(1+x)^\alpha \ge 1 + \alpha x$ is true.

Can proof by contradiction and counterexample be used in this way ?

Comment: you dont know $\alpha = 2 $

Comment: Also, $\alpha $ is an integer ?

Comment: @Lemur I just chose a random $\alpha > 1$ to satisfy the assumption.

Comment: the negation of $\forall $ is $\exists$

Comment: You can't really do that, because now you just have one example of where the statement holds. When you prove by contradiction, you must show that it always leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Visit: http://www.virtualnerd.com/algebra-1/linear-inequalities/multi-step-examples/variables-both-sides/contradiction-no-solution-definition